# Problem using \includeonly

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling, external-files, include, subfiles

I have a problem using the `\includeonly` command. I have a large document and I wanted to split it up into sections- each section would be in its own file and I would compile only the current chapter that I am working on. The ideal case (please suggest if you know how to do this) would be to have the full document appear in the produced PDF, but only the current section's contents be updated as I do the compilations (such that it does not take a long time to compile everything). Anyhow, I have the following document structure:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{newclude}

\includeonly{11_bayesiandecisionmaking}

\begin{document}

\include*{01_introduction}
\include*{02_probability1}
\include*{03_probability2}
\include*{04_statistics}
\include*{05_RS_FOSM}

\include*{11_bayesiandecisionmaking}

\end{document}
```

I was promised that using `\include` the references to equations in other files that are not cited in `\includeonly` (e.g. `02_probability1`) would be maintained so I should not get the (**??**) missing reference symbols. However, this is what is happening to me right now - only `11_bayesiandecisionmaking` contents appear in the compiled PDF and all references to other files that are not "included" are missing (I get (**??**)). Do you know how to fix this? Even better, do you know how to include all of the chapters in the final PDF but only compile selectively, e.g. only `11_bayesiandecisionmaking`? Thanks for helping!

Comment: In order to get the references right, you have to compile the document twice with all `\include`  enabled, i.e. comment out `\includeonly`, compile twice and then start to use `\includeonly` again.

Comment: why `newinclude` ? But anyway you need to process the full document first so that latex knows all the cross references, then you can use includeonly on later runs to skip chapters, using the saved information from earlier runs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `newclude` in order to not have page breaks between sections.

Comment: The suggestion does not work. After compiling twice with includeonly commented out, the references stay (i.e. no ??) for the first compilation after putting back includeonly, but after the second compilation they disappear again. PS. I am using TeXlipse.

Comment: @space_voyager: Either your setup is wrong (I don't use such editors at all) or you have something in your code that prevents the usage of references. Like David Carlisle, I don't suggest `newclude`. (Never heard of it before)

Comment: @space_voyager I don't think `newclude` is fully reliable. Note that it's been unmaintained for more than 15 years. I also think that the gain in time with `\include` instead of `\input` is negligible.

Comment: @egreg The problem was `newclude`, it works now. But how do I selectively compile using `\input`?

Comment: You can't that is what `\include` does (and the forced page breaks are needed so that latex can make references and page references without reprocessing the files) with `\include` just comment out the ones you don't want to process, and ignore the ?? in drafts.

Comment: @space_voyager Why do you need “selective compilation”? If it's for saving time, don't worry. If it's for producing PDF files for each section, then a page break is necessary anyway, so the standard `\include` will do.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will stick with \input. Thanks for all your input!

Comment: @space_voyager: Have you seen my `\InputOnly` solution at all? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first run must see all included files to get the `aux` files
of each included one:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\includeonly{11_bayesiandecisionmaking}
\begin{document}

\include{01_introduction}
\include{02_probability1}
\include{03_probability2}
\include{04_statistics}
\include{05_RS_FOSM}

\include{11_bayesiandecisionmaking}

\end{document}
```

Now you can enable the `\includeonly`. Then it can load all existing `aux` files.