# Suppress reference undefined warning for specific chapters

Tags: macros, warnings

I have got a large document with over 400 pages and over 20 different chapters. Every chapter is separately included via an`\input{}` command.

While editing a specific chapter, I exclude the most other chapters to reduce compiling time. But if my included chapter refers to an excluded chapter I get (linke expected) a reference undefined warning. This warnings are very annoying and I would like to suppress them.

So is there a possibility to suppress all reference warnings for specific chapters? I thought about setting a variable at the beginning of every chapter and if this variable is not defined, then suppress all reference warnings for this chapter.

Comment: You can use `\includeonly` which keeps references for excluded files, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32058/ at the end of the answer.

Comment: Sounds good, please write it as an answer

Comment: There are already several answers about this, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280572/problem-using-includeonly.