Unexpected "multiply defined label" when importing with import and using xr for referencing, on Overleaf
I'm working on a multi chapter thesis and I thought it would be a good idea to separate each one in a standalone .tex file, so that I could easily work without having to compile the whole document each time.
I read Overleaf's own explanation and all was going well until I started my second chapter and I found myself having to reference the first one through the xr package, which I soon found out to be a bit of a pain on Overleaf.
I developed a workaround to using a latexmkrc file because it didn't work for me and I don't really understand what it does or how to code in Perl: since I won't be changing my 1st chapter often (hopefully), I just downloaded its output.aux, renamed it after my 1st chapter .tex and reuploaded it into Overleaf, in a separate folder, like so:

To my surprise it actually worked fine, but when I ran my main file, which imports every chapter sequentially, I was submerged by 25+ Label '[LabelName]' multiply defined. warning messages.
After some digging I found out that commenting \externaldocument{Capitoli/aux/Capitolo 1} in my 2nd chapter's preamble solved the issue.
I made an example project to show this. It has three files:
Chap1
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lipsum 1}\label{sec:Lipsum1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

Chap2
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{aux/Chap1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lipsum continued}
In Sec. \ref{sec:Lipsum1} we had Lipsum 1. Now:\\
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

and main:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\import{./}{Chap1}
\import{./}{Chap2}
\end{document}

Clearly for this to work you need to run in on my Overleaf, where Chap1.aux is and can be read.
If you run main.tex you'll get Label 'sec:Lipsum1' multiply defined., as if it gets defined once when importing Chap1 and then when calling \externaldocument{/aux/Chap1} in Chap.2
Any information on how to avoid this (if avoidable) without eccessively complicating things or completely overhauling would be very much apprecciated.

yiu are mixing two mechanisms xr and import and so including the aux file twice and getting multiple lable warnings. Personally, I would not use either and simply use the standard \include

welcome! it seems like the wrong solution to use xr for part of the same document. why not just \include each chapter and then \includeonly in the preamble to control what's compiled? (as @DavidCarlisle already said.)

Thank you both for your answers. Works about fine but if I \includeonly my second chapter alone now all \ref to the firts chapter are undefined, even if I \include all of my chapters in the document body
-Edit: Ok sorry I found a solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280572/problem-using-includeonly
